# Face-to-face with a trace at the end of a calculus case - what to do next?

Tags: calculus, matrices, matrix-calculus, trace

EDIT: Several have confessed, the verse makes no sense. Lest they vote it to close, I will replace it with prose.

I am interested in finding the derivative $\partial h/\partial U$ , where

$h(U) = \lambda \sum_{i,j} U_{i,j}^2$

I first replace this expression with an operator that will work better with differentials, like this one:

$\sum_{i,j} U_{i,j}^2 = tr(U^TU)$

Now I take the differential of $h$ and work it out:

$\mathbf{d}h = \lambda\mathbf{d}tr(U^TU) = \lambda tr(\mathbf{d}(U^TU))
=\lambda tr\left((\mathbf{d}U)^TU + U^T\mathbf{d}U\right)$

$=\lambda tr((\mathbf{d}U)^TU) + \lambda tr(U^T\mathbf{d}U) = \lambda tr(U^T\mathbf{d}U)+ \lambda tr(U^T\mathbf{d}U) = 2\lambda tr(U^T\mathbf{d}U)$

In order to find the derivative $\partial h/\partial U$, I need to have the $\mathbf{d}U$ term isolated at the far right of the expression. That is, I want to reduce the expression above into this form:

$\mathbf{d}h = A\mathbf{d}U$

Because then:

$\partial h/\partial U = A^T$

However, I can't figure out how to carry out this reduction, and I was wondering if someone knew what I can do next.

Comment: Does the answer have to rhyme?

Comment: Plain old prose will do!

Comment: The point of good mathematical writing is to clearly convey ideas.  The goal of MSE is to create a repository of well-written questions and answers.  While I enjoy the cheekiness of posting your question in verse, I find that it hinders clarity, and renders the question unsuitable for this site.  I have therefore voted to close this question for lack of clarity.  If you would be so kind as to rephrase your question (and, while your at it, improve the formatting of the displayed math), I would be more than happy to rescind my vote.

Comment: Done! I'm not sure what you mean by improving the format of the displayed math though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you were already so close, this answer need not be verbose:

You've got the final formula wrong. It is:
If $dh = Tr(AdU)$, then $\frac{\partial h}{\partial U} = A^T$.

Plugging this in, you have the answer is $2 \lambda U$.

One thing you could keep in mind is $\frac{\partial X}{\partial Y}$ tells you how the elements of $X$ vary with the elements of $Y$ and that gets reflected in the final dimensionality.

If $dX$ is a scalar and $Y$ is a matrix, like in the correct case, you get a matrix with the same dimensions as $Y$, with each element sort of telling you how the scalar varies with that element.

If $dX$ were a matrix, the final answer would have bigger dimensionality.

Source: Table 3.2 of *Complex-Valued Matrix Derivatives* by Hjørungnes.